# Prometheus container level buffered memory metric is missing

Tags: memory, kubernetes, metrics, prometheus

When i checked prometheus custom metrics, i see container_memory_cache but container level memory buffer data is not available.. When i run `vmstat -S M` command.. i can get buffered memory as below. But in kubernetes architecture, running this command on each pods will be wasting resources.. Is there any alternative way to get these datas for each pods?In addition to that, vmstat metrics also do not have buffered memory data too... Any idea? Thanks

```
vmstat -S M
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0      0    456      2  19594    0    0     6    39    4    3  7  5 87  0  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of information regarding container memory usage in cgroups, for example

> /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/{id}/memory.stat

Such files could be accessed from node OS and will provide you with all available information regarding container memory usage.

However, as far as I understand, buffered memory is not available inside containers to avoid double caching by node OS and container itself.

Comment: but, strange thing is inside of container, i see non-zero values for buffered memory. should i ignore that? This was confused me

Comment: I guess this is happening because many tools, which can show you memory usage, are unaware of the fact that they are running inside the container, and show you info about node memory usage.